# Mongoose .save function is not persisting in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose to save a record from a defined schema to MongoDB. However it just creates a record like the one below.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d677825fd64c7018a74ffc"), "__v" : 0 }
```

I am using:

- Mongoose version 4.0.3
- npm version 3.3.12
- node version 5.1.0

Here is my index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = require('./schema');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users');

// Parameters are: model name, schema, collection name
var User = mongoose.model('User', schema, 'testing');

var user = new User({
    name: 'John Smith',
    email: 'john@smith.io'
});

user.save(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    User.find({ email: 'john@smith.io' }, function(error, docs) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log(require('util').inspect(docs));
            process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

And my schema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    match: /.+@.+\..+/,
    lowercase: true
  },
  loggedInCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});
```

I did see that there were other questions relating to this but I couldn't get any of them to work. I am working through a tutorial and have tried literally running the exact same code as the tutorial but to no avail.

**Update 1 3/3 -**
Following up on the recommendation in the comments I uninstalled v4 and re-installed 3.8 but I'm still getting the same issue. Just a 'blank' record with an object id in it. I also tried explicitly pointing the mongod --dbpath to my data directory but I don't believe that is the issue because a record is being created, it is just not persisting the data that I'm pushing.

**Update 2 3/3 -**
Using

```
mongoose.set('debug',true)
```

I am getting the below response

```
  Mongoose: testing.insert({ __v: 0, _id:ObjectId("56d915355a07ee0f1c000001") }) {}
Mongoose: testing.find({ email: 'john@smith.io' }) { fields: undefined }
```

But no record is found. I am returned `[]`

Comment: Your sample codes works well under mongoose v3.8.0..

Comment: thanks, maybe its an issue with v4? I'll try 3.8 tonight

Comment: Added an update based on @zangw recommendation

Comment: Add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to help you analysis it

Comment: Does this result `{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d677825fd64c7018a74ffc"), "__v" : 0 }` from `console.log(require('util').inspect(docs));`? or you check `testing` collection in `users` db?

Comment: Thats what I see when I look in the collection. The console.log returns []

Comment: That is so weird, any output after adding `mongoose.set('debug', true)`?

Comment: So it looks like it isn't sending the schema data

    `[4] → node index.js
    Mongoose: testing.insert({ __v: 0, _id:ObjectId("56d915355a07ee0f1c000001") }) {}
    Mongoose: testing.find({ email: 'john@smith.io' }) { fields: undefined }
    []`

Comment: In my test, I just run `node index.js` directly, it work well in my local. based on your logs, something different?

Comment: Ok.... this is weird. I created a brand new directory else where and copied everything over and now it worked. I have no idea why

Comment: How did you run your code? I notice the `schema.js` required in your `index.js`, Do you run your code with `node index.js` under the `index.js` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105325/discussion-between-zangw-and-alex).

Comment: Hi zangw , @Alex : What was the solution. I am getting the exact error..